# XPath: select an element with more than 3 comments

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to select an element whose text contains more than 3 comments with a specific value.

I have tried:

```
//*[count(self::comment()[. = "comment_text"]) > 3]
```

and

```
//*[count(comment()[. = "comment_text"]) > 3]
```

and variations of that with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `comment()[. = "comment_text"]` Must it be that strict? 
does `count(./comment()[contains(., "comment_text")])>3` change anything?

Comment: Your second approach is correct (as long as you don't try and use a double quoted string literal inside a `select` attribute value that is itself surrounded by double quotes - either use double quotes around `comment_text` and single quotes around the `select` or vice-versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works with XSLT 2.0 - you did not say which version you are working with.

However, it is common practice to escape the `>` character to `gt` and you must pay attention to nested quotes (quotes must be single if nested inside double quotes and vice versa).

**Sample Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
   <true><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--></true>
   <wrong1><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--></wrong1>
   <wrong2><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--><!--comment_text--><!--wrong_text--></wrong2>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[count(comment()[.='comment_text']) gt 3]">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<true/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I'm not sure exactly what was going wrong in my test environment, but it now works. Thanks for responding.

Comment: You're welcome. There might be differences between XPath 1.0 and 2.0 though. I briefly tried this with an XSLT 1.0 processor and got no output.

Comment: If you are in XSLT 1.0 then you need to use `&gt;` rather than just `gt`.  Apart from that it should work fine.  XSLT 2.0 has both the `gt` (compare single values) and `>` (existentially quantified comparison of sequences) operators, 1.0 only has the `>` one.

Comment: I had made that change, but still I get no output from the w3schools XSLT Tryit environment. But perhaps this is rather due to a dubious processor than to the change of versions.

Comment: I just tried the 1.0 version of your stylesheet with `xsltproc` and it worked correctly.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if the w3schools tool is dubious...

Answer (score 0):

and just in case the version of xslt is 1.0 and the way you have used, use the below expression:

```
//*[count(comment()[. = 'comment_text']) &gt; 3]
```